# AframeJS - how to completely destroy a scene?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm developing a Vue app with an AframeJS component. I'd like to know the proper method to destroy an Aframe scene (listeners, timers, animation-frames, etc.)?

Right now, when I destroy my aframe-vue-component, the aframe `animation-frame` timers continue to fire, which drags on performance for the rest of the app.

I pored over the [aframe docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/) and didn't find a sensible method.

Thanks

Comment: [Github issue](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3463) on the topic

Answer (score 0):

You could load the A-Frame experience in an iframe and reload / change url and hide it when you don’t need it.